# PostgreSQL send email via pgMail error 38000

Tags: postgresql

I have problem with send e-mail via pgMail on Ubuntu 18.04. I do from in this article: [brandolabs.com](http://brandolabs.com/pgmail)

Previously I installed package

sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-pltcl-12 and run createlang pltclu [YOUR DATABASE NAME]

On end I was executed file sql from [pgMail1.4](https://github.com/captbrando/pgMail/releases/tag/v1.4):

pgMail.sql, example.setup.sql and example.execute.sql, but when I run

```
select pgmail('Send From ','Send To ','Subject goes here','','HTML message body here.');
```

or

```
update orders set paystatus = 'y' where id = 1;
```

I received error 38000

```
couldn't open socket: Name or service not known
name: error
length: 629
severity: ERROR
code: 38000
where: couldn't open socket: Name or service not known
    while executing
"socket $myHost $myPort"
    (procedure "__PLTcl_proc_228303" line 15)
    invoked from within
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README of the project mentions this requirement:

> *** BEFORE ADDING THE PROCEDURE TO YOUR DATABASE YOU MUST DO THE** 
>    **FOLLOWING!!!                                                 ***
>
> Replace the text <ENTER YOUR MAILSERVER HERE> with the fully qualified
>   domain name for your mailserver.  i.e., mail.server.com.
>
> Replace the text <ENTER YOUR DATABASESERVER HERE> with the fully
>   qualified domain name for your database server.  i.e., db.server.com.

Based on your error message, you forgot to do this or put an invalid value for the mailserver. In generally you would use `localhost` on a Unix system to talk to the local mail server.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot replace <ENTER YOUR EMAIL SERVER HERE> and <ENTER YOUR DATABASE SERVER HERE>